# jquery focussing on newly unhidden input box

Tags: html, css, forms

I need to show a hidden  when a particular  is selected (with arrow keys) and next  element is focussed using a TAB key press.

I have tried many combinations including 'showing' the  on key down =9 and separately focussing the element on key up.

Whatever I do, the  shows but the focus moves to the  button. If I cycle through all page elements using TAB eventually it focusses the  but never does it first time.

Code :

```
<HTML><HEAD>

<SCRIPT SRC="js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js">
$( document ).ready(function() {

});
</SCRIPT>


</HEAD><BODY>

<FORM>
<SELECT ID='in1'>
<OPTION VALUE='green'>Green
<OPTION VALUE='blue'>Blue
<OPTION VALUE='red'>Red
<OPTION VALUE='Other'>Other

</SELECT>

<INPUT TYPE='text' ID='in2' STYLE='display:none;'>

<INPUT TYPE='submit'>
</FORM>

<SCRIPT>

$('#in1').keydown(function(e) {

   var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
   if (code == '9') {

$("#in2").css( "display", "block");
$(':text').focus();

   }

});

</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: Try closing the <option> tags, close the <html> at the end and add a doctype. Also try $("#in2").show().focus(); Not sure what happens to input when set to display block (normally inline)

Comment: Thanks. Tried various combinations of those. Still won't focus on teh unhidden <INPUT>. I have also tried splittig the <SCRIPT> so that focus() is on keyup. This doesn't focus first time but if cycle through TABs for a full cycle, then skips from 'Other' to unhidden <INPUT> to focus it.

Comment: So script now reads:       <SCRIPT>

$('#in1').keydown(function(e) {

   var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
   if (code == '9') {

$('#in2').css("display", "block");

   }

});

$('#in1').keyup(function(e) {

   var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
   if (code == '9') {

$('#in2').focus();

   }

});

</SCRIPT>

Comment: Solved it. Flagging the use/non-use of the hidden <INPUT> helped. Script ended up as: <SCRIPT>

doneflag=0;
$('#in1').keydown(function(e) {
var optext=$('#in1').val();

   var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
   if (code == '9' && optext=='Other') {

$('#in2').css("display", "block");

   }

});

$('#send').focus(function() {
var optext=$('#in1').val();

if (doneflag==0 && optext=='Other') {

$('#send').blur();
$('#in2').focus();
doneflag=1;
  }
else {
$('#send').focus();
doneflag=0;
 }

});


</SCRIPT>